# How would you go about parsing Markdown?

Tags: parsing, markdown

> Edit: I recently learned about a project called CommonMark, which
>   correctly identifies and deals with the ambiguities in the original
>   Markdown specification. http://commonmark.org/ It has great C# library
>   support.

You can find the syntax [here](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

The source that follows with the download is written in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), which I have no intentions of honoring. It is riddled with regular expressions, and it relies on [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hashes to escape certain characters. Something is just wrong about that!

I'm about to hard code a parser for [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). What is experience with this?

If you don't have anything meaningful to say about the actual parsing of Markdown, spare me the time. (This might sound harsh, but yes, I'm looking for insight, not a solution, that is, a third-party library).

To help a bit with the answers, regular expressions are meant to **identify patterns**! NOT to parse an entire grammar. That people consider doing so is foobar.

- If you think about Markdown, it's fundamentally based around the concept of paragraphs.
- As such, a reasonable approach might be to split the input into paragraphs.
- There are many kinds of paragraphs, for example, heading, text, list, blockquote, and code.
- The challenge is thus to identify these paragraphs and in what context they occur.

I'll be back with a solution, once I find it's worthy to be shared.

Comment: @cletus is writing a markdown parser, see http://www.cforcoding.com/search/label/markdown

Comment: I ended up doing the same. However, I'm not trying to parse markdown as if it was a formal grammar, because it's clearly not. I applied different regular expressions in a recursive manner. And in several passes. That worked out very well.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, any chance other curious users such as myself can see your attempt at parsing markdown?

Comment: @jmlopez Sorry, I don't have access to that source any longer, if you need a markdown parser, there is a NuGet package available that can be used. The idea is simple enough though, just apply a series of regular expression in passes, start by paritioning the input in paragraphs then try to identity what kind of paragraph it is, and so on. Finally, parse links and character styles within the paragraphs themselves.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren, I figured that much. I'm currently working on my own (I love to reinvent the wheel) using python (Although there is already one). I am having some trouble identifying the blocks though. I'll take a look at the NuGet package. thanks

Comment: In case the discussion is still relevant: I've recently created a decent semantic markup language called Markeven as a part of [Circumflex](https://github.com/inca/circumflex) (for Scala), which resembles Markdown but has more strict rules and some unique features. Markeven has been ported recently to NodeJS under the codename [Rho](http://npmjs.org/package/rho).

Comment: You should look at [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org). It splits text into lines. Then it looks at how these lines start and relate to each other.

Comment: related (if you are looking for java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784525/markdown-to-html-with-java-scala

Comment: If anybody need parser without renderer.  You can use my markdig fork: https://github.com/glebov21/markdigNoRenderer

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The only markdown implementation I know of, that uses an actual parser, is [Jon MacFarleane](https://GitHub.Com/JGM/)’s [peg-markdown](https://GitHub.Com/JGM/PEG-Markdown/). [Its parser](https://GitHub.Com/JGM/PEG-Markdown/tree/master/markdown_parser.leg) is based on a [Parsing Expression Grammar](http://PDOS.CSAIL.MIT.Edu/%7Ebaford/packrat/) parser generator called [peg](http://Piumarta.Com/software/peg/).

---

EDIT: [Mauricio Fernandez](http://EigenClass.Org/R2/) recently released his [Simple Markup Markdown parser](https://GitHub.Com/MFP/OcsiBlog/blob/master/simple_markup.ml), which he wrote as part of his [OcsiBlog](https://GitHub.Com/MFP/OcsiBlog/) Weblog Engine. Because the parser is written in [OCaml](http://Caml.INRIA.Fr/), it is *extremely* simple and short (268 SLOC for the [parser](https://GitHub.Com/MFP/OcsiBlog/blob/more-markdown-compat/simple_markup.ml), 43 SLOC for the [HTML emitter](https://GitHub.Com/MFP/OcsiBlog/blob/more-markdown-compat/simple_markup__html.ml)), yet [*blazingly* fast](http://EigenClass.Org/R2/writings/markdown-redux-html-generation) (20% faster than [discount](http://WWW.Pell.Portland.Or.Us/%7Eorc/Code/markdown/) (written in hand-optimized C) and *sixhundred* times faster than [BlueCloth](http://Deveiate.Org/projects/BlueCloth/) ([Ruby](http://Ruby-Lang.Org/))), despite the fact that it isn't even optimized for performance yet. Because it is only intended for internal use by Mauricio himself for his weblog, there are a few deviations from the [official Markdown specification](http://DaringFireball.Net/projects/markdown/syntax/), but Mauricio has created [a branch which reverts most of those changes](https://GitHub.Com/MFP/OcsiBlog/tree/more-markdown-compat/).

Comment: interesting. perhaps I will try converting that as an f# project

Comment: @Benjol Same old story: no time :/

Comment: Terrence Parr (co author of ANTLR) has written one for ANTLR 4: https://github.com/parrt/mini-markdown

Answer (score 18):

I released a new parser-based Markdown Java implementation last week, called [pegdown](http://github.com/sirthias/pegdown).
pegdown uses a PEG parser to first build an abstract syntax tree, which is subsequently written out to HTML. As such it is quite clean and much easier to read, maintain and extend than a regex based approach.
The PEG grammar is based on John MacFarlanes C implementation "peg-markdown".

Maybe something of interest to you...

Comment: This is now officially deprecated

Answer (score 7):

If I was to try to parse markdown (and its extension [Markdown extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/)) I think I would try to use a state machine and parse it one char at a time, linking together some internal structures representing bits of text as I go along then, once all is parsed, generating the output from the objects all stringed together.

Basically, I'd build a mini-DOM-like tree as I read the input file.
To generate an output, I would just traverse the tree and output HTML or anything else (PS, LaTex, RTF,...)

Things that can increase complexity:

- The fact that you can mix HTML and markdown, although the rule could be easy to implement: just ignore anything that's between two balanced tags and output it verbatim.
- URLs and notes can have their reference at the bottom of the text. Using data structures for hyperlinks could simply record something like:

  ```
  [my text to a link][linkkey]
  results in a structure like: 
      URLStructure: 
      |  InnerText : "my text to a link"
      |  Key       : "linkkey"
      |  URL       : <null>
  ```
- Headers can be defined with an underline, that could force us to use a simple data structure for a generic paragraph and modify its properties as we read the file:

  ```
  ParagraphStructure:
  |  InnerText    : the current paragraph text 
  |                 (beginning of line until end of line).
  |  HeadingLevel : <null> or 1-4 when we can assess 
  |                 that paragraph heading level, if any.
  ```

Anyway, just some thoughts.

I'm sure that there are many small details to take care of and I'm pretty sure that Regexes could become handy during the process.
After all, they were meant to process text.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably read the syntax specification enough times to know it, and get a feel for how to parse it.

Reading the existing parser code is of course brilliant, both to see what seems to be the main source of complexity, and if any special clever tricks are being used. The use of MD5 checksumming seems a bit weird, but I haven't studied the code enough to understand why it's being done. A comment in a routine called `_EscapeSpecialChars()` states:

> We're replacing each such character with its corresponding MD5 checksum value;
>   this is likely overkill, but it should prevent us from colliding with the escape
>   values by accident.

Replacing a single character by a full MD5 does seem extravagant, but perhaps it really makes sense.

Of course, it'd be clever to consider creating a "true" syntax, for a tool such as [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) to get out of the regex bog.

Comment: That MD5 thing still bothers me, also the excessive string manipulation has to be slower than any actual decent parser you could write yourself.

Comment: Flex is really only half the parser; once you have tokenized the
input, you need to determine what the tokens mean.  This is what a
parser generator is for.  There are lots of them.  ("Parser combinator",
"recursive-descent" and "LALR(1)" are key words to google for.)

Comment: @jrockway: that is true of course, I guess I shrugged and thought "but if he reads up on Flex, he'll find Bison automatically". :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If Perl isn't your thing, there are Markdown implementations in [at least 10 other languages](http://markdown.infogami.com/).  They probably don't all have 100% compatibility, but tend to be pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

[MarkdownPapers](http://markdown.tautua.org) is another Java implementation whose parser is defined in a [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC) grammar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a programming language that has more than three other
users, you should be able to find a library to parse it for you.  A
quick Google-ing reveals libraries for CL, Haskell, Python,
JavaScript, Ruby, and so on.  It is highly unlikely that you will need
to reinvent this wheel.

If you really have to write it from scratch, I recommend writing a
proper parser.  With this technique, you won't have to escape things
with MD5 hashes.  (I agree that if you have to do something like this,
it's time to reconsider your design.)

Comment: I'm up for the challenge. I looked at libraries but they're just awful. Ugly and stupid. I'm considering writing the parser in F# because I need a F# project but I'll probably end up doing it in C#.

Comment: Hopefully F# has a library like Parsec; if so, this will be a fun project ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/) you can find a JavaScript-implementation of Markdown. It also relies heavily on regular expressions, as this is just the fastest and easiest way to parse the text.

But it spares the MD5 part.

I cannot help directly with the coding of the parsing, but maybe this link can help you one  way or another.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries available in a number of languages, including php, ruby, java, c#, javascript. I'd suggest looking at some of these for ideas.

It depends on which language you wish to use, for the best way to implement it, there will be idiomatic and non idiomatic ways to do it.

Regexes work in perl, because perl and regex are best friends.

Comment: Regex and perl are best friends because somebody said so. There's no more truth to that fact than it's historical ancestry, that it has been used like that. I have no use for something like perl.

Comment: Then don't use it.. Also, learn irony.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown is a JAWL (just another wiki language)

There are plenty of open source wiki's out there that you can examine the code of the parser. Most use REGEX

Check out the screwturn wiki, is has an interesting multi pass formatter pipeline, a very nice technique - see /core/Formatter.cs and /core/FormatterPipeline.cs

Best is to use/join an existing project, these sorts of things are always much harder than they appear

Comment: I thought that was easy until my parser totally freaked out on lines like: `**hello *world***` the ambiguity if the * is a bitch.