# How to parse Markdown in PHP?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, markdown, tree-grammar

First, I know, there already is a Markdown parser for PHP.
I also took a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605434/how-would-you-go-about-parsing-markdown) but it doesn't answer to my question.

Obviously, even if the title mention PHP, if it's language agnostic, because I'd like to know what are the step I've to go through to do that.

I've read about [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), but I've to admit, I didn't really understand the example provided with the PHP parser.

I've also read about [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

I've found [Zend_Markup_Parser_Textile](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Markup/Parser/Zend_Markup_Parser_Textile.html) which seems to construct a so called "Token Tree" (what's about it?) but it currently [unusable](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Markup/Parser/Zend_Markup_Parser_Textile.html). (Btw, Textile is not Markdown)

So, concretely, how would you go to this?

Obviously I though about using Regex but, I'm afraid.

Because Markdown supports several syntaxes for the same element (Setext and atx).

Could you give some starting point?

Answer (score 38):

You should have a look at [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org).

It parses Markdown text the way people do. First, it divides texts into lines. Then it looks at how these lines start and relate to each other. Finally, it looks for special characters to identify inline elements.

Comment: This seems to be the best option as it has the more amount of stars in github. Just one question though, the Class is pretty small, why doesn't he the parse() in the __construct() ?

Comment: @David天宇Wong You could parse several pieces of Markdown strings with one instance of Parsedown. This way you could set up some options once and use them throughout multiple Markdown strings. Right now there aren't many options, but it is future-proof this way.

Comment: Why do people consider converting Markdown to HTML "parsing"? Shouldn't parsing return a parse tree?

Answer (score 11):

There is [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/) that seems to be popular, you could start by looking at its source.

Answer (score 5):

Also, there is an object-oriented implementation of Markdown which is faster: [markdown-oo-php](https://github.com/garygolden/markdown-oo-php)

Answer (score 2):

[Ciconia](https://github.com/kzykhys/Ciconia) - A New Markdown Parser for PHP is a good one I found.

You just need 3 things to do :

1.Install Ciconia and parse file according to the [document](https://github.com/kzykhys/Ciconia).
2. Add corresponding css theme to make it nice, like [github markdown style](https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css) or [here](https://github.com/jasonm23/markdown-css-themes/blob/gh-pages/markdown.css).
3. Add syntax highlighting javascript, like [google Javascript code prettifier](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

Then everything will look pretty good.

If you want a complete example, here is my working demo for github style markdown:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Ciconia\Ciconia;
use Ciconia\Extension\Gfm;

$ciconia = new Ciconia();
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\FencedCodeBlockExtension());
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\TaskListExtension());
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\InlineStyleExtension());
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\WhiteSpaceExtension());
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\TableExtension());
$ciconia->addExtension(new Gfm\UrlAutoLinkExtension());
$contents = file_get_contents('Readme.md');
$html = $ciconia->render($contents);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Excel to Lua table - Readme</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./github-markdown.css">
        <style>
            .markdown-body {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                min-width: 200px;
                max-width: 980px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 45px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article class="markdown-body">
        <?php
            # Put HTML content in the document
            echo $html;
        ?>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regexes.

```
<?php

/**
 * Slimdown - A very basic regex-based Markdown parser. Supports the
 * following elements (and can be extended via Slimdown::add_rule()):
 *
 * - Headers
 * - Links
 * - Bold
 * - Emphasis
 * - Deletions
 * - Quotes
 * - Inline code
 * - Blockquotes
 * - Ordered/unordered lists
 * - Horizontal rules
 *
 * Author: Johnny Broadway <johnny@johnnybroadway.com>
 * Website: https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900
 * License: MIT
 */
class Slimdown {
    public static $rules = array (
        '/(#+)(.*)/' => 'self::header',                           // headers
        '/\[([^\[]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/' => '<a href=\'\2\'>\1</a>',  // links
        '/(\*\*|__)(.*?)\1/' => '<strong>\2</strong>',            // bold
        '/(\*|_)(.*?)\1/' => '<em>\2</em>',                       // emphasis
        '/\~\~(.*?)\~\~/' => '<del>\1</del>',                     // del
        '/\:\"(.*?)\"\:/' => '<q>\1</q>',                         // quote
        '/`(.*?)`/' => '<code>\1</code>',                         // inline code
        '/\n\*(.*)/' => 'self::ul_list',                          // ul lists
        '/\n[0-9]+\.(.*)/' => 'self::ol_list',                    // ol lists
        '/\n(&gt;|\>)(.*)/' => 'self::blockquote ',               // blockquotes
        '/\n-{5,}/' => "\n<hr />",                                // horizontal rule
        '/\n([^\n]+)\n/' => 'self::para',                         // add paragraphs
        '/<\/ul>\s?<ul>/' => '',                                  // fix extra ul
        '/<\/ol>\s?<ol>/' => '',                                  // fix extra ol
        '/<\/blockquote><blockquote>/' => "\n"                    // fix extra blockquote
    );

    private static function para ($regs) {
        $line = $regs[1];
        $trimmed = trim ($line);
        if (preg_match ('/^<\/?(ul|ol|li|h|p|bl)/', $trimmed)) {
            return "\n" . $line . "\n";
        }
        return sprintf ("\n<p>%s</p>\n", $trimmed);
    }

    private static function ul_list ($regs) {
        $item = $regs[1];
        return sprintf ("\n<ul>\n\t<li>%s</li>\n</ul>", trim ($item));
    }

    private static function ol_list ($regs) {
        $item = $regs[1];
        return sprintf ("\n<ol>\n\t<li>%s</li>\n</ol>", trim ($item));
    }

    private static function blockquote ($regs) {
        $item = $regs[2];
        return sprintf ("\n<blockquote>%s</blockquote>", trim ($item));
    }

    private static function header ($regs) {
        list ($tmp, $chars, $header) = $regs;
        $level = strlen ($chars);
        return sprintf ('<h%d>%s</h%d>', $level, trim ($header), $level);
    }

    /**
     * Add a rule.
     */
    public static function add_rule ($regex, $replacement) {
        self::$rules[$regex] = $replacement;
    }

    /**
     * Render some Markdown into HTML.
     */
    public static function render ($text) {
        $text = "\n" . $text . "\n";
        foreach (self::$rules as $regex => $replacement) {
            if (is_callable ( $replacement)) {
                $text = preg_replace_callback ($regex, $replacement, $text);
            } else {
                $text = preg_replace ($regex, $replacement, $text);
            }
        }
        return trim ($text);
    }
}


echo Slimdown::render ("# Title

And *now* [a link](http://www.google.com) to **follow** and [another](http://yahoo.com/).

* One
* Two
* Three

## Subhead

One **two** three **four** five.

One __two__ three _four_ five __six__ seven _eight_.

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

More text with `inline($code)` sample.

> A block quote
> across two lines.

More text...");
```

Origin https://gist.github.com/jbroadway/2836900