# Regex to create html from custom code

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a field of text where users can write specific command to get some html.

For example:

```
Text Text Text Text

[*] first entry
[*] second entry
[*] 3rd...

Text Text
```

This text should be converted with regex to something like this:

```
text text

<ol>
 <li>FirstEntry</li>
 <li>Second</li>
 ..
</ol>

text text
```

Any suggestion?

The regex that matches the line with entry is something like this:

```
/\[\*\].+/i
```

**The problem is how** to insert correctly the `<ol>` and `</ol>`

### My solution

I was thinking I could parse all line of text and when the parser encouter the first line that starts with [*] then put an `<ol>` Same thing for the `</ol>`

Until now I have made the script that converst single `[*] ...` to `<li> ...`

http://codepad.org/yzRVupON

```
preg_replace('/\[\*\](.+)/i','<li>$1</li>',$str);
```

I need the `<ol>` part

### My implementation

http://codepad.org/NNgC6uko

Comment: You want to take a look at phps regex function `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. but I knew that function and I Don't see how I could use that

Comment: Why, you use a regex to match the patterns `[*] first entry` and so on and for each such match the callback function you implement is called. Inside that function you can output whatever markup you want, for example `<li>FirstEntry</li>`.

Comment: That's not the question :). The question is more like how to insert correctly <ol> and </ol>

Comment: Well, maybe by doing the same using another regex pattern? Though that is even easier, you don't need a callback but can use the plain `preg_replace()` function.

Comment: Please make an example: http://codepad.org/8OyDau57

Comment: Sorry, no, I won't make your homework :-) You claim you know how to use the functions, so use them. Post what you have so far, your attempts and say what specific part it is you cannot get to work the way you want to. Please understand that this is not a forum to get free labor.

Comment: @arkascha: that's not an homework. It is a suggestiong how to proceed.   I have made the simple script that converts that with <li> http://codepad.org/yzRVupON but i still need suggestiong for <ol> part

Comment: Sorry, but that 'simple script' you mention does not at all consider the hints I gave you.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks for help anyway. If you know and if you want post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this kind of parsing with regular expressions is probably not the way to go; it might be OK for very simple scenarios but the more features you try to put in the harder it will get -- until the point where it becomes unmaintainable.

I would suggest borrowing parsing techniques from e.g. various MarkDown parsers out there; see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116187/how-to-parse-markdown-in-php) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605434/how-would-you-go-about-parsing-markdown) for more information (there are others too).

Back to the original question: if you are constrained to only using regular expressions you could try matching the whole "list block" first with something like

```
/^(\s*\[\*\].*?$)+/m
```

(the multiline mode [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is essential)

You can then produce the output by breaking the matched text down into individual list items with your current regex and then surrounding the result with `<ol></ol>`.

Comment: What About if i put every line into an array... Then I parse the whole array and when I see there is the first line starting with [*] i insert an `<ol>` ?

Comment: That's the description of a very simple parser, so it's a step in the right direction. But check out existing code first, there's no sense in writing your own if you can adapt something that' been tested.

Comment: that's the problem of reinventing the wheel. But I don't need al the features of markdown or other parser...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** to put tags on either side?
Something like the below perhaps.

```
$string = <<<EOF
Text Text Text Text

[*] first entry
[*] second entry
[*] 3rd...

Text Text
EOF;

$pattern = '/(\[\*\])([\d\D]+)(\[\*\].*)/';
$replacement = '<ol> ${1}${2}${3} </ol>';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

$pattern = '/\[\*\](.+)/i';
$replacement = '<li>${1}</li>';

echo  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
Text Text Text Text

    <ol>
        <li> first entry </li>
        <li> second entry </li>
        <li> tag 3rd... </li>
    </ol>

Text Text
```

Comment: @m.buettner Oh. Will look for a cooler regex. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: check my answer... i have made a little script

Comment: @yes123 cool. I'm still going to try to write purely `preg_match` solution. (for the fun of it) ;)

Comment: @yes123's script is much better though, easily extensible, to a more generic solution. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

That's my implementation.  Working code: http://codepad.org/NNgC6uko

This scritp is easly customizabile with any sort of translation from a command to HTML

```
function parseText($txt) {

    $lines = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/',$txt,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $newLines = array();

    $lastTag = '';
    foreach($lines as $k=>$v) {

        $currentTag = $v[0];

        //$newLine = $v;
        $newLine = preg_replace('/^\* (.+)$/','<li>$1</li>',$v);

        if ($currentTag=='*' && $lastTag != '*')
            $newLines[] = '<ol>';

        else if ( $lastTag == '*' && $currentTag != '*' )
            $newLines[] = '</ol>';  

        $newLines[] = $newLine;



        $lastTag = $currentTag;

    }

    print_r($newLines);
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but use explode() instead of preg_split to get your new lines.  It should be faster for a larger string.  Regex is an awesome tool, but more expensive to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483497/how-to-put-string-in-array-split-by-new-line.  E.G. $lines = explode("\n", $txt);

Comment: \n is only for linux... windows uses \r\n... also using explode multiple lines will be sperated.. \n\n\n