# PHP preg_match URL formatting

Tags: php, url, formatting, preg-replace

I'm not too sure how I should word that title, apologies. x_x

I'm basically trying to convert a string to a formatted URL similar to how Reddit/Stackoverflow does it.

Eg. `[Hello World](http://google.com)` = [Hello World](http://google.com)

Both of the following work, but they don't work when combined together.

`preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]/", ... //Works for [Hello World]`

`preg_replace("/\(([^\)]+)\)/", ... //Works for (Hello World)`

`preg_replace("/\[([^\]]+)\]/\(([^\)]+)\)/", ... //Doesn't work`

Regex confuses me x_x Help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `/\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/`? Removing a `/` in the middle that would cause an error in the statement.

Comment: Its called markdown, Why not implement it properly, then you can use all the markdown to html markup features https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown or more parsers can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116187/how-to-parse-markdown-in-php

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605434/how-would-you-go-about-parsing-markdown

Answer (score 0):

Use  this `\[([^\[\]]*)\](.*)`

```
$input_lines="[Hello World](http://google.com)";

preg_replace("/\[([^\[\]]*)\](.*)/", "$1", $input_lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '[Hello World](http://google.com)';
preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $str);
```