# What exactly is a lexer's job?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, markdown, tokenize, lexer

I'm writing a lexer for Markdown. In the process, I realized that I do not fully understand what its core responsibility should be.

The most common definition of a lexer is that it translates an input stream of *characters* into an output stream of *tokens*.

```
Input         →  Output 
(characters)     (tokens)
```

That sounds quite simple at first, but the question that arises here is **how much semantic *interpretation*** the lexer should do before handing over its output of tokens to the parser.

---

Take this example of Markdown syntax:

```
### Headline
*This* is an emphasized word.
```

It might be translated by a lexer into the following series of tokens:

#### Lexer 1 Output

```
.headline("Headline")
.emphasis("This")
.text"(" is an emphasized word.")
```

But it might as well be translated on a more granular level, depending on the grammar (or the set of lexemes) used:

#### Lexer 2 Output

```
.controlSymbol("#")
.controlSymbol("#")
.controlSymbol("#")
.text(" Headline")
.controlSymbol("*")
.text("This")
.controlSymbol("*")
.text"(" is an emphasized word.")
```

It seems a lot more practical to have the lexer produce an output similar to that of **Lexer 1**, because the parser will then have an easier job. But it also means that the lexer needs to semantically *understand* what the code means. It's not merely mapping a sequence of characters to a token. It needs to look ahead and identify patterns. (For example, it needs to be able to be able to distinguish between `**Hey* you*` and `**Hey** you`. It cannot simply translate a double asterisk `**` into `.openingEmphasis`, because that depends on the following context.)

According to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605434/2062785) and the [CommonMark definition](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#appendix-a-parsing-strategy), it seems to make sense to first break down the Markdown input into a number of blocks (representing one or more lines) and then analyze the contents of each block in a second step. With the example above, this would mean the following:

```
.headlineBlock("Headline")
.paragraphBlock("*This* is an emphasized word.")
```

But this wouldn't count as a valid sequence of tokens because some of the lexemes ("*") have not been parsed yet and it wouldn't be right to pass this `paragraphBlock` to the parser.

---

So here's my question:

#### Where do you draw the line?

How much semantic work should the lexer do? Is there some hard cut in the definition of a lexer that I am not aware of?

What would be the best way to define a grammar for the lexer?

Comment: 'How much semantic interpretation the lexer should do': None. Zero. Nada. Nulla. Rien.

Comment: So you're saying even if the lexer read an opening parenthesis `(` in the source code of a programming language, it should always return `.openingParenthesis`, regardless of whether it's part of a string/comment or not? Because that would already be a semantic interpretation, to distinguish between parentheses that have a meaning in code and parentheses that don't. It's already saying: "This parenthesis has another meaning than that parenthesis." Even if the lexer doesn't know *what* the meaning is, it *does* know that there *are* two different meanings and needs to distinguish between them.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. It is up to the parser to parse, not the lexer. Scanners deal with regular languages, parsers with CFLs. NB This is syntax, not semantics. NB 2 It is up to the scanner to *remove* comments, not return them to the oarssrparser in any way. It is possible that your language as defined so far is ambiguous.

Comment: @user207421 Comments and string literals are lexed as a single token, so since tokens can't be inside other tokens, a `(` inside a comment or string literal would *not* produce a `(` token. No lexer I've ever seen leaves the handling of comments and string literals to the parser.

Comment: @Mischa If you went the first way, then what should the result be for `### Head *line*`? `.headline(.text("Head"), .emphasis("line"))`? Then your lexer would be generating a tree and thus actually be a parser (of course, you might very well decide that something as simple as Markdown doesn't need a lexer and just write a lexerless parser instead). Generally, anything that can be nested, can't be a single token. So the result of a lexer should be more like your second version (though I'd personally treat `###` as a single token).

Answer (score 0):

BNF is used to describe many languages / create lexers and parsers

MOST use a Look right 1 to define a unambiguous format.

Recently I was looking at playing with SQL BNF
https://github.com/ronsavage/SQL/blob/master/sql-92.bnf

I made the decision that my lexer would return only terminal token strings. Similar to your option 1.

- '('
- ')'
- 'KEWORDS'
- '-- comment eol'
- '12.34'
- ...

Any rule that defined the syntax tree would be left to the parser.

- `<Document> := <lines>`
- `<Lines>    := <line> [<Lines>]`
- `<line>     := ...`